# how to left align the Jquery datatable pagination buttons

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

Any ideas on how to left align the Jquery datatable pagination buttons?
by default top buttons are aligned center, and bottom buttons are aligned right.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

You need to use !important to override the existing style applied to the paginator.

```
.dataTables_paginate {
  float: left !important;
}
```

Comment: Any explanation on why this was down voted? It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

`div.dataTables_paginate {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. But its not working...i changed in the css file like this:.dataTables_paginate { width: 44px; * width: 50px; float: left; text-align: left; } but still the same way its dispalying.... previously it was right and i changed it to left. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1457957 Why is there a `*` in there?

Comment: i dont know, it was there by default in the css with datatable example

Comment: Hmm, honestly I don't even remember what I did to my instance[s] (I rewrote parts of the JS to make it fit in visually with Bootstrap. I'll look at all of my changes and get back to you later (if someone else doesn't solve this first)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did with a default `datatable` (no `dom`/`sDom` setting) so that the pagination control is under the  `x of y` info, both items left-aligned and at the bottom of the table:

```
Showing 1 to 25 of NN entries
First Previous 1 2 3 4 5 Next Last
```

I added this style:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        div.dataTables_info {
            position: absolute
        }

        div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_paginate {
            float: unset;
            text-align: left;
            padding-top: 28px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
```

with these settings:

```
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "iDisplayLength": 25,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]],
```